# Splitting a string by a regex in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string that is formatted like the following:

```
... {{word1}} {{word2}} .... etc
```

I need to extract all the words, located inside the '{{' and '}}' tags.

What is the most efficient way to retrieve the words from the string in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using pattern `/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/` you can extract all the words

```
preg_match_all("/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

http://ideone.com/pyB4D

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$vars = '{{this}} {{is}}{{a}} {{test}}';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/{{([^}]+)}}/', $vars, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Like that?

Comment: I think the \w is more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to look into is the PHP [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

Comment: What delimiter are you using?